# How to compute the cosine similarity of a list of scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have a list of sparse vector:

```
print(type(downsample_matrix)) # Display <class 'list'>
print(type(downsample_matrix[0])) # Display <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

I would like to use the function scikit learn `cosine_similarity` on `downsampled_matrix` but I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5997ca6abb2d> in <module>()
     19         downsample_matrix.append(vector)
     20         downsample_coefficient = 0
---> 21 similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(downsample_matrix)
     22 plt.matshow(similarity_matrix)
     23 plt.show()

/home/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in cosine_similarity(X, Y, dense_output)
    908     # to avoid recursive import
    909 
--> 910     X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
    911 
    912     X_normalized = normalize(X, copy=True)

/home/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y, precomputed, dtype)
    104     if Y is X or Y is None:
    105         X = Y = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=dtype,
--> 106                             warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype, estimator=estimator)
    107     else:
    108         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=dtype,

/home/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have no problem when my list is made of `nd.array`:

```
print(type(downsample_matrix)) # Display <class 'list'>
print(type(downsample_matrix[0])) # Display <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I apply cosine_similarity on my list of sparce vectors?

Comment: `np.array(array,....)` tries to turn the input list into one array. With a list of matching numpy arrays that works (test it). It does not work for sparse matrices.  Test that your self.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` or `sparse.vstack` might work combine the matrices into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a small sparse matrix.  Note that it is not a subclass of `ndarray`.  It stores its data in 3 arrays - data and indices:

```
In [196]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
In [197]: M
Out[197]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [198]: M.data
Out[198]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [199]: M.indices
Out[199]: array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
In [200]: M.indptr
Out[200]: array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int32)
```

If I try to make an array from a list of this matrix, I get an object dtype array, with 3 elements (pointers to this one matrix):

```
In [201]: alist = [M,M,M]
In [202]: np.array(alist)
Out[202]: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:294: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, using <, >, or !=, instead.
  "using <, >, or !=, instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)

array([ <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

If in addition I specify the dtype, I get your error:

```
In [203]: np.array(alist,dtype=int)
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It can't convert the list into an array of numbers.

But if it's a list of dense arrays, I get a 3d array:

```
In [204]: np.array([M.A,M.A,M.A],dtype=int)
Out[204]: 
array([[[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]]])
In [205]: _.shape
Out[205]: (3, 2, 3)
```

I can also concatenate the sparse matrices with a sparse version of `vstack` or `hstack`.

```
In [206]: sparse.vstack(alist)
Out[206]: 
<6x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [207]: _.A
Out[207]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Note the shape, (6,3).  A sparse matrix is always 2d.

`sparse.vstack` passes the task to `sparse.bmat`, which constructs a new sparse matrix from 'blocks'.  It does so by joining the `coo` representations of the blocks with a appropriate offsets.

Since `cosine_similarity` expects a 2d array or sparse matrix, you'll have to use the `sparse.vstack` to join the matrices.  Or reshape the result of the 3d array join

```
In [212]: cosine_similarity(sparse.vstack(alist))
Out[212]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
In [213]: cosine_similarity( np.array([M.A,M.A,M.A],dtype=int).reshape(-1,3))
Out[213]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

A =  np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
A_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(A)

similarities = cosine_similarity(A_sparse)
print('pairwise dense output:\n {}\n'.format(similarities))
```

Result

```
pairwise dense output:
 [[ 1.          0.36514837  0.31622777]
 [ 0.36514837  1.          0.28867513]
 [ 0.31622777  0.28867513  1.        ]]
```

My scipy

```
print (scipy.__version__)
0.19.0
```

Comment: My use case is different, my matrix A would be full of sparse vector <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

Comment: @mel If all sparse vectors have the same dimensions (i.e. live in the same feature space), convert this list to a sparse matrix first and then use sklearn's `cosine_similarity` function as suggested.